# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..30, inclusive: -1 Flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, bloc

I'm getting this error at first build of the `ScrollablePositionedList` (which is a calendar).

Initially I declare an empty `List<DateTime> calendar = [];` that gets filled with dates with the state (I'm using flutter_bloc) and call a method that checks if today's date is in the list and scroll to that index, otherwise scrolls to index 0 (1st day of the month).

Apart from the Bloc's InitialState which is empty, I have two different states, one is  `TodayDate` used for building the widget on current month when screen loads, and the other is `NewDate`, which is used to rebuild widget when changing month in the calendar.

I get the error only when `TodayDate` state is received (see Print 1), but when changing month everything works as expected(see Print 2 and 3).

I can't spot why on the first widget build it throws the error as the available data is the same as print 3.
I initially thought it might had to do with the `InitialState` being empty but then `TodayDate` state comes in with data and should fix the error. Also, prints show the error after State transaction.

Can you see anything wrong in my implementation?
As always thank you very much for your time and help.

---

## Widget:

```
Expanded(
//                            child: ListView.builder(
//                            controller: scrollController,
                            child: ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
                              itemScrollController: scrollController,
                              itemCount: calendar.length,
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                                  CalendarCell(
                                      day: calendarFormat
                                          .format(calendar[index]),
                                      borderColor: isSelectedDay[index] == true
                                          ? Colors.white
                                          : dateCheckIsToday.format(
                                                      calendar[index]) ==
                                                  dateCheckIsToday
                                                      .format(DateTime.now())
                                              ? Colors.greenAccent
                                              : getDayNameShort.format(
                                                          calendar[index]) ==
                                                      'Sun'
                                                  ? Colors.redAccent
                                                  : Colors.orangeAccent,
                                      isSelected: isSelectedDay[index],
                                      onTap: () {
                                        BlocProvider.of<CalendarBloc>(context)
                                            .add(UpdateCalendarSelectedDay(
                                                isSelectedDay, index));
                                        BlocProvider.of<CalendarBloc>(context)
                                            .add(GetOpeningTimeSlots(
                                                weekday:
                                                    '${getDayNameShort.format(calendar[index])}',
                                                date: calendar[index]));
                                      },
                            ),
                            flex: 2,
                          ),
```

---

## BlocListener:

```
if (state is TodayDate) {
                  setState(() {
                    displayDate = state.newDate;
                    print(displayDate);
                    calendar = state.calendar;
                    isSelectedDay = state.isSelectedDay;
                    scrollToIndex(
                        calendar); 
// RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..30, inclusive: -1
                  });
                }
                if (state is NewDate) {
                  setState(() {
                    displayDate = state.newDate;
                    calendar = state.calendar;
                    isSelectedDay = state.isSelectedDay;
                    scrollToIndex(calendar); // works perfectly
//                    print('calendar is ${state.calendar}');
//                    print('isDaySelectedDay is ${state.isSelectedDay}');
                  });
                }
```

---

## scrollToIndex method:

```
void scrollToIndex(List<DateTime> calendar) {
    print('scrollToIndex called');
    indexToScrollTo = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < calendar.length; index++) {
      dateCheckIsToday.format(DateTime.now());
      if (dateCheckIsToday.format(calendar[index]) ==
          dateCheckIsToday.format(DateTime.now())) {
        indexToScrollTo = index;
        break;
      }
    }
    print('indexToScrolTo is: $indexToScrollTo');
    scrollController.jumpTo(
        index: indexToScrollTo); //, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
  }
```

## Print 1: `TodayDate`state prints for actual month of May:

```
flutter: Event is GetMonth : {actual date :2020-05-17 08:08:41.044548}
flutter: Transaction is Transition { currentState: InitialState : { date: 2000-01-01 00:00:00.000, calendar : [], isSelected :[]}, event: GetMonth : {actual date :2020-05-17 08:08:41.044548}, nextState: TodayDate : { date: 2020-05-17 08:08:41.044548, calendar : [2020-05-01 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-02 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-03 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-04 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-05 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-06 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-07 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-08 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-09 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-10 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-11 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-12 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-13 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-14 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-15 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-16 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-17 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-18 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-19 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-20 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-21 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-22 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-23 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-24 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-25 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-26 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-27 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-28 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-29 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-30 00:00:00.0<…>
flutter: 2020-05-17 08:08:41.044548
flutter: scrollToIndex called
flutter: indexToScrolTo is: 16

════════ (4) Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..30, inclusive: -1
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

## Print 2:`NewDate`state when changing month to June:

```
flutter: Event is NextMonth : {actual date :2020-05-17 08:08:41.044548}
flutter: Transaction is Transition { currentState: TodayDate : { date: 2020-05-17 08:08:41.044548, calendar : [2020-05-01 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-02 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-03 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-04 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-05 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-06 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-07 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-08 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-09 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-10 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-11 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-12 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-13 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-14 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-15 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-16 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-17 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-18 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-19 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-20 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-21 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-22 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-23 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-24 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-25 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-26 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-27 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-28 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-29 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-30 00:00:00.000, 2020-05-31 00:00:00.000], isSelected :[false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, fals<…>
flutter: scrollToIndex called
flutter: indexToScrolTo is: 0
```

## Print 3: `NewDate` prints for changing month back to May:

```
flutter: Event is PreviousMonth :{actual date :2020-06-17 00:00:00.000}
flutter: Transaction is Transition { currentState: NewDate : { date: 2020-06-17 00:00:00.000, calendar : [2020-06-01 00:00:00.000, 2020-06-02 00:00:00.000, 2020-06-03 00:00:00.000, 2020-06-04 00:00:00.000, 2020-06-05 00:00:00.000, 2020-06-06 00:00:00.000, 2020-06-07 00:00:00.000, 2020-06-08 00:00:00.000, 2020-06-09 00:00:00.000, 2020-06-10 00:00:00.000, 2020-06-11 00:00:00.000, 2020-06-12 00:00:00.000, 2020-06-13 00:00:00.000, 2020-06-14 00:00:00.000, 2020-06-15 00:00:00.000, 2020-06-16 00:00:00.000, 2020-06-17 00:00:00.000, 2020-06-18 00:00:00.000, 2020-06-19 00:00:00.000, 2020-06-20 00:00:00.000, 2020-06-21 00:00:00.000, 2020-06-22 00:00:00.000, 2020-06-23 00:00:00.000, 2020-06-24 00:00:00.000, 2020-06-25 00:00:00.000, 2020-06-26 00:00:00.000, 2020-06-27 00:00:00.000, 2020-06-28 00:00:00.000, 2020-06-29 00:00:00.000, 2020-06-30 00:00:00.000],isSelected :[false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, <…>
flutter: scrollToIndex called
flutter: indexToScrolTo is: 16
```

As prints show when when changing month and receiving `NewDate` state the widget updates correctly and when changing back to actual month it also behaves as expected jumping to today's date. So why does `TodayDate` fail, that carries same data, and does the same call to the scroll method as `NewDate`?

## Update:

Using a `Timer` to delay the call of the `scrollToIndex` method makes it work properly. Hope this helps to understand where the problem is.

```
if (state is TodayDate) {
                  setState(() {
                    displayDate = state.newDate;
                    print(displayDate);
                    calendar = state.calendar;
                    isSelectedDay = state.isSelectedDay;
                    Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 50), () {
                      scrollToIndex(calendar);
                    });
                    // timer makes it work

// RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..30, inclusive: -1
                  });
//                  scrollToIndex(calendar);
                }
```

Comment: @Diggy. thanks for the editing. It's quite clearer.

Comment: No worries. Hope you find the answer!

Comment: sure I will ;)..dough I'm getting mad at this one..just to scroll to current day...thanks again. cheers

Comment: A little workaround is to put a 50ms delay to the method call  when receiving the first state..